# Put basic Auth credentials in jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, oauth

I need help from the experts. Although I have been programming for over 2 years now, I am still unclear sometimes of security protocols.

Pretty sure I know that I should not put basic auth credentials in my jQuery script, but would like confirmation about this.

I am implementing paypal checkout flow. In order to make a follow up request to paypal to get the order details and display them on a thank you page, I would need to get the token and then use that as part of the basic auth credentials to make a request for the order. This means of course hard coding my credentials inc client id + secret on the jquery script, I am sure this is NOT ok, as they could be hacked.

At the moment I do not want to make my own server and store them there, although I am certain this is the way to do it.

What do you think?

Comment: where's your app going to be hosted? You just don't put the client credentials as part of your client code as it's visible to everyone.

Comment: It's a wordpress site, I have some DOM manipulation with jquery, is that considered client code? I mean, there is a script tag to my wordpress server, can this be hacked?